# Why does Kotlin use forloop to cause the index to be null? (indices)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

This is my code to run in android. Sometime throw **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(length=0; index=0)**

```
val list = mutableListOf<String>()
for (i in list.indices){
    val item = list[i]
}
```

But when I use **forEachIndexed** , The code works well.

Does anyone know the reason?
And Which method is usually preferred?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Is this mutable list shared by multiple threads?

Comment: `list.indices` returns `0..-1` for empty lists, but this should skip your `for` loop anyway. `forEachIndexed` and `for (i in list.indices)` should behave the same, so I'm quite surprised you get this result. Could you please share the actual code that reproduces the problem? Do you compute indices somehow?

Comment: The code you posted runs fine in a playground, without any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know the reason?

Both `for (i in list.indices)` and `forEachIndexed` should behave the same way.
Your problem might come from places in the code that you haven't shared. Do you manipulate indices? Do you mutate the list in another thread at the same time?

> Which method is usually preferred?

If there is a functional shortcut, it's usually preferred over a loop, because it has less boilerplate. This makes it easier to read (we see the intent more clearly) and also there are less opportunities to make mistakes.

So I would definitely prefer:

```kotlin
list.forEachIndexed { i, item ->
   // use item and i in the loop body
}
```

Over:

```kotlin
for (i in list.indices) {
    val item = list[i]
    // use item and i in the loop body
}
```

The only exception is when the loops are in very performance sensitive spots (those are quite rare), because using a `for` can save an `Iterator` usage.